# cant have access to a listbox from another form

Tags: c#, listbox

there are 2 forms in my project ( Form3 and Form5) . in Form3 the program generates 5 random numbers and put them in a listbox . and after a few seconds Form5 opens and asks user the count of a specific number in a listbox . there's a check button and a textBox in Form5 . so i wrote the checking part in check button in Form5 to check how many numbers of a specific number is in listbox . The problem is i cant have access to listbox in form3 from form5 . i also set the listbox modifier to public . but it didnt work ! here's my code :

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {


        private int ticks=0;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        int i;

        int n;
        Random r = new Random();


        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    n = r.Next(0, 5);
                    listBox1.Items.Add(n);
                }
                timer1.Start();


            }

---------------------------------------------------------------------
 public partial class Form5 : Form
    {

        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }
        public int number;
        int x;
        int k = 0;
        public int count=0;



        Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
        Random r = new Random();

 private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            number = r.Next(0, 5);

            txtRandom.Text = String.Format("Numbers of  {0}", number);


        }

private void btn_chk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (k = 0; k < frm3.listBox1.Items.Count; k++)
            {
                if (frm3.listBox1.Items[k].Equals(number))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }



                int countOfnumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtCount0.Text);

                if (countOfnumber == count)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("well done !");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Oops ! wrong !");
                }
            }
```

can anyone pls help ?

Comment: You can use context to access the variable if it is out of scope. Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to pass a ref to the control in to form5 or pass the lists datasource into form 5 for you to analyze. Why not just use 1 form?

Comment: tnx guys , well , i dont want user see the listbox when time is out , so i used another form . how can i pass a ref to the control ?